# node.js displays "undefined" on the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, undefined

Recently I installed node.js on my Windows 7 machine.

On execution of JavaScript, I get an *undefined* message along with successful execution of the expression.

What's wrong here? I have not noticed any other side effects.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js REPL "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186565/node-js-repl-undefined)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just write `"hello world";` and hit enter... it will return `"hello world"` instead of `undefined`, thus no `undefined` is displayed. `console.log` returns `undefined` and also logs arguments to console so you get multiple messages.

Comment: Thanks Esailija. When I don't enter any function or any character; then also "undefined" is displayed. Can you please explain what is happening under the hood?

Comment: @SandeepGB, what do you expect for not having any input? :P The return value of not entering anything makes most sense to be `undefined`

Comment: I was trying to understand whats going on. alessioalex answered my question :)

Answer (score 53):

The JavaScript functions always return something. If you don't specify something to return in the function, 'undefined' is returned by default (you can check this out in Firebug too).

Don't worry though, this doesn't affect anything, you can ignore it.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the reply. Is there a way to get rid of 'undefined', what should be the syntax?

Comment: If you make a program (web app or command line), you'll never get "flying" undefineds, so don't worry about that.

Comment: When I don't enter any function or any character; then also "undefined" is displayed. Can you please explain what is happening under the hood?

Comment: What's happening under the hood. Enter asdasd for example and see this error: at REPLServer.eval (repl.js:80:21) ... So behind the scenes there's an eval() function which returns 'undefined'.

Comment: Thanks. Got it now :) I should start looking at how things are implemented and not just how to get it working.

Answer (score 19):

As pointed out by others, javascript function will always return undefined if you do not specify any return value. You can just ignore it. It's not going to cause any harm.
But if it's annoying you too much then you can turn it off in repl. Repl has this property **ignoreUndefined** which is set to false by default. You can set it to true.
Try this:

```
module.exports.repl.ignoreUndefined = true;
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, the question was made some years ago, but there is still another way to explain what is happening here.

Try next command:

```
console.log("Hello World") || "Bye World";
```

As mentioned function `console.log()` returns `undefined` normally and you can choose a better return value. Since Non-strict (abstract) comparison considers `undefined` equal to `false` the `||` operator allows you that choice.

Considering that it is just a debugging tool, this is unnecessary in general use, but helps to understand that console **displays** text sent to stdout and also evals the command and **displays** the returned value, or undefined if no value was received.

Comment: Hi @Melo, I think this code can be re-written to a nicer console.log("Hello World") || "Bye World".

Answer (score 4):

If you need to turn on `ignoreUndefined` from inside a module, you can use the following line to simulate [AvinashB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2077318/avinashb)'s answer without typing into the console by yourself:

```
process.stdin.emit('data', "module.exports.repl.ignoreUndefined = true;\n");
```

Answer (score 4):

`node` also prints `undefined` because **IN GENERAL**, it displays the return value of each command and `console.log` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because console.log has (null/undefined) return type 
to solve this issue.. have a function returning a string..
then log that function returned value...
that will overcome the undefined issue..

```
const addNotes= function(msg)
{
    return msg;
}
console.log(addNotes('say hello'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore it, no need to worry at all. I too had the same issue when I called the function without any return type. So node used to print undefined return type for the called function.

```
function emitEvent(eventname){
    eventEmitter.emit(SIV_EVENT);
}
console.log(emitEvent());
```

Check undefined here, https://nodejs.org/api/util.html.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid seeing `undefined` output from commands when using Node's `repl` module, set `ignoreUndefined` to `true` in [`repl.start`](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html#repl_repl_start_options).

Answer (score 0):

Use middle where in your index file

```
app.use(express.json())
```