# node.js REPL "undefined"

Tags: node.js

Upgraded from node 0.4.11 to 0.6.15, and noticed the REPL (running node with no arguments) keeps dumping "undefined" after most commands or carriages returns...

It's distracting and driving me batty, how do you disable this?

```
> 
undefined
> 
undefined
> 
undefined
> 
undefined
> var x = 2
undefined
> x
2
>
```

Comment: Related, [node.js displays "undefined" on the console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8457389/418183).

Comment: Thanks, I understand what is undefined, but I want to get rid of it when running the repl from the cmd line.   It's distracting.

Comment: I don't quite get why if I type var a=2; then why is it printing undefined ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the Node.js [REPL](http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html) documentation page.

Specifically this:

> If `ignoreUndefined` is set to true, then the repl will not output return value of command if it's `undefined`. Defaults to `false`.

Sample code:

```js
var net = require("net"),
    repl = require("repl");

repl.start(null, null, null, null, true);
```

Sample output:

```
> var x
> var blah
```

Additionally you could alias `node` to

```
node -e "require('repl').start(null, null, null, null, true)"
```

Comment: I saw that, but sorry to be dense - I don't understand how to set this when running node from the command line.   I'm not launching repl from a script.   This mentions repl.start(...), etc.

Comment: Expanding on @deltanovember's sample code, to get the behavior you want, use ``node -e "require('repl').start(null, null, null, null, true)"`` from the command-line. Perhaps alias it?

Comment: But what if I only want it to display undefined when it matters that undefined was returned? Like in the case of var and let where there was never a chance for anything to be returned?

Answer (score 18):

Another way of invoking node without the undefined returns of commands is by:

```
node -e "require('repl').start({ignoreUndefined: true})"
```

from the command line

Comment: I like this so much better. I can actually tell what it's doing.

Answer (score 7):

```
# node -i -e "repl.repl.ignoreUndefined=true"
```

My new **_node** alias (v6.11.2).

The advantage I see in this over others here, is that it affects the current/default repl context ..which is where all my node command history was!

Answer (score 2):

On similar lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186565/node-js-repl-undefined/46366498#46366498)

You can run this `repl.repl.ignoreUndefined=true` from inside REPL session.

A sample code:

```
Welcome to Node.js v12.13.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> var x
undefined
> repl.repl.ignoreUndefined=true
true
> var y = 10
> _
true
> console.log(y)
10
>
```