# How to avoid undefined output from Node REPL

Tags: node.js

I'm putting together a training video for the basics of Node. I'm demonstrating REPL and it seems no matter what I do I get "undefined". I've read several posts here and everyone seems to say it's normal because javascript always returns null but it just seems odd and I think my viewers will think I'm an idiot.

Is there anyway to turn it off or am I doing something wrong? I've attached a screen shot of some very simple stuff that returns undefined

[image]
[image]

Comment: look on this question, please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186565/node-js-repl-undefined

Comment: A little surprised to see my question down-voted.  There are lots of answers to the question on line and most of them are wrong. Not finding the needle in the haystack hardly seems a reason to downvote the question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in windows:

```
node -e "require('repl').start({ignoreUndefined: true})"
```