# nodejs REPL output on same line

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, read-eval-print-loop

I'm building a CLI app with nodejs with native `REPL`. A dumb sample is:

```
const repl = require('repl')
const myApp = require('myApp')
repl.start({
  eval: (input, context, filename, callback) => {
      const result = myApp(input)
      callback(null, result)
  },
  writer: (result) => result 
         ? 'my result: ' + result
         : ''  // <--- empty result
})
```

Everything is fine, but a newline is created for every response of the app. I'd like to override this behavior, and decide whether to create a new line or not.

**Example**
Let's pretend the app to be a calculator:

```
$ node index.js
add 5
add 3
result
8
```

Because `add` command doesn't have any result, a new command should be inserted in the very next line. However, what I'm getting from the above code is:

```
$ node index.js
add 5

add 3

result
8
```

with an empty line added after any 0`add` call.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

So I found out there's a parameter I could set, `ignoreUndefined`. If true, when you call `callback(null, undefined)` (empty result case), it won't add a new line.

Thus, in the above example:

```
const repl = require('repl')
const myApp = require('myApp')
repl.start({
  ignoreUndefined: true,
  eval: (input, context, filename, callback) => {
      const result = myApp(input)
      callback(null, result)
  },
  writer: (result) => result 
         ? 'my result: ' + result
         : undefined  // <--- empty result
})
```

docs: https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

similar question: [node.js REPL "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10186565/node-js-repl-undefined)