# why undefined in node.js hello world example after console.log

Tags: node.js

i just started with node.js . So for starting with Hello World example [node.js beginner book](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) . when i type the command `console.log("Hello world");` . Its prints Hello World on console . That what i expect from this code but in next line its also prints the `undefined`

i install the nodejs from this link for windows [installation of nodejs for windows](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation)

here below is screenshot also for this

[image]

Comment: javascript function must return anything so it returns undefined , when i use console.log("Hello World");return; it doesnot print undefined

Comment: The Node shell outputs the return value of whatever you input, in this case, undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js displays "undefined" on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457389/node-js-displays-undefined-on-the-console)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Every JavaScript function returns something. When you define function like this:

```
function test() {
    var x = 1;
}
```

then `test()` returns `undefined`. The same applies to the `console.log` function. What it does is that it passes the arguments to the display. And that's all. Thus it returns `undefined`.

Now Node JS shell works in such a way that whenever you input a function, variable, etc. it displays the value it returned. Thus `console.log('Hello world!');` passes `Hello world!` to the screen and returns `undefined`, which then Node JS shell displays.

That's more or less how it works.

Comment: When I type `for (c in {}) {  };` in the node console I still get `undefined`. I'm pretty sure that `for` is NOT a function. So I'm suspecting that your answer is incorrect or at least incomplete.

Comment: Sorry for this late response, totally missed the comment. Anyway it applies to all expressions. Every JavaScript expression (not only functions) returns something even though not every result can be assigned to a variable.

Comment: Is there a reference for this that every expression whatsoever returns something?