# Console returns undefined

Tags: javascript

So I've hijacked the console function:

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
console.log = function (a) {
    log.call(console, a);
    submitmsg("Log", a);
};
```

This has the desired effect. However, it also returns "undefined" as an unexpected bonus.

I can't figure out why which leads me to think there is something slightly wrong here.

[image]

Hello world is generated by `log.call(console, a)` as expected

`submitmsg()` is my custom function

This is working exactly how I want. As I said though, I'm slightly concerned that it is also returning "undefined" for reasons I do not understand.

---

**Note:** The following code was posted by the OP as an answer to the question. The comments on the answer have been moved to the comments on the question.

---

So should the correct code be the following?

```
var log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.log, console);
console.log = function (a) {
    return log.call(console, a);
    submitmsg("Log", a)
};
```

Comment: this still also returns "undefined"

Comment: That's because `log.call` returns `undefined`. That's why I'm not sure what you're trying to acheive... the native `console.log` method returns `undefined`. What do you want to return?

Comment: sorry i have resubmitted in more detail

Comment: Following your edit to the question, I get exactly the same thing in my console if I call the real `console.log` method. That's because `console.log` returns `undefined`.

Comment: Your absolutely right, sorry James, couldnt see the forest for the trees and all that

Comment: No problem :) Glad I could help you to understand it!

Comment: And now `submitmsg` doesn't work at all, is it intended?

Comment: possible duplicate: [node.js displays “undefined” on the console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8457389/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, it's because you are not explicitly returning anything from the function. When you don't return a value from a function, it implicitly returns `undefined`.

For example:

```
function example() {}
console.log(example()); //undefined
```

This is defined in the [`[[Call]]` internal method specification](http://es5.github.com/#x13.2.1) (relevant points in bold):

> 1. Let funcCtx be the result of establishing a new execution context for function code using the value of F's [[FormalParameters]] internal
>      property, the passed arguments List args, and the this value as
>      described in 10.4.3.
> 2. Let result be the result of evaluating the FunctionBody that is the value of F's [[Code]] internal property. If F does not have a
>      [[Code]] internal property or if its value is an empty FunctionBody,
>      then result is (normal, undefined, empty).
> 3. Exit the execution context funcCtx, restoring the previous execution context.
> 4. If result.type is throw then throw result.value.
> 5. **If result.type is return then return result.value.**
> 6. **Otherwise result.type must be normal. Return undefined.**

Comment: Hi James,

i did start there, however that functionality overrides the console's output not add to it, although your answer is correct it would not actually output to the console

Comment: @Fibrewire - What are you expecting to be returned? The native `console.log` method returns `undefined`, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: Latest link as of 2022: https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist