# string manipulation in javascript giving out errors

Tags: javascript, string

I have this doubt, this code is supposed to turn the first character in the word into caps

```
function ucFirst(str) {
    var newStr = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        newStr += str.charAt(i);

    }

    return newStr
}
alert(ucFirst("john"));
```

this will print out "John" along with an undefined in the console.

Now I tried the exact same thing using the array values

```
function ucFirst(str) {
    var newStr = str.str[0].toUpperCase();
    for (var i = 1; i < str.length; i++) {
        newStr += str.str[i];
    }
    return newStr;
}
alert(ucFirst("john"));
```

I get this error in console `"Cannot read property '0' of undefined"`

Why is it so?

Comment: Shouldn't the code be `var newStr = str[0].toUpperCase()`

Comment: Your variable `str` has no property `str`. I guess you got a typo there.

Comment: Thanks guys, my other doubt. why does undefined show up in the console ?

Comment: Can't you just do `return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1, str.length);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works. Replace all instances of `str.str[` with `str[`

It reads out undefined because you're calling your string in object context and trying to refer to a property `str`, which is not a property, thus `undefined`.  There is no `String.str` on the class object, nor is there a `str.str` on your string *object* (object used loosely) that you're passing.

---

Note: I want to add that while doing the replacement will *fix* your code, this is not the most optimal way to apply a propercase casting.

Comment: You have the right answer, but the wrong explanation.  It doesn't resolve to `j` - it's trying to find the `str` property of `str`, which is undefined, and then the `0` property of that.

Comment: @Dennis I think you're right. Looked at it too fast was thinking more like `str[str[0]]`.  Note to self: only fools rush in

Answer (score 1):

```
str.str[0].toUpperCase();
```

should just be

```
str[0].toUpperCase();
```

If that isn't the case, you should try `console.log(str)` and find out what exactly `str` is but I believe this is your problem.

Comment: When you declare a function in the console, it's always going to return an undefined. This is because you don't specifically return anything unless the function is called. A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360904/console-returns-undefined

Comment: yeah, it's working. Just wanted to know why the undefined shows up.

Comment: @Bazinga777 I updated my comment. There's a similar question related to it.