# Trouble with creating an object in Javascript with the var keyword

Tags: javascript, variables, console, google-chrome-devtools

Hello, I am having a trouble with creating an object in Javascript.
I found something strange that when I used console in Chrome:

```
function person(){this.Name = "John";}
var a = new person()
```

**Result:** `undefined`

But if I do this

```
b = new person()
```

**Result:** `Person {Name: "John"}`

Is there any difference between using `var` keyword or not using it, when creating an object in javascript?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsbin.com/nilef/1/edit. Omitting `var` creates a global variable.

Comment: duplicate of [What is the function of the var keyword in ECMAScript 262 3rd Edition/Javascript 1.5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/what-is-the-function-of-the-var-keyword-in-ecmascript-262-3rd-edition-javascript) for the question. The strangeness just comes from what Chrome Console displays (or not). A *`var` statement* does not have a result value, while an *assignment expression* has.

Answer (score 3):

Check the value of a, it's actually the same as b. `undefined` is just the result of the evaluation of the expression `var a = new person()`.

Comment: but I can't access to a when I do
    a.Name

Answer (score 0):

Inside a function, all undeclared variables are global. Only those declared with var are local.
So in terms of scope yes it differs.
If you are assigning value inside a function and printing outside, that explains your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome returns undefined for any statement that doesn't explicitly `return` a value.

e.g.

```
var j = "Jenny from the block";
```

returns

> > undefined

To fully run your code try

```
function person(){this.Name = "John";}
var a = new person();
console.log(a.Name);
```

Comment: You don't need `return`, any expression statement will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

It's just how the browser console works. It returns the returns value of whatever you execute. In this case, your statement returns undefined. Not scoping issues since the console runs under window scope. Happens in both firefox and chrome.

[Console returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360904/console-returns-undefined)