# What is happening when I call console.log within console.log?

Tags: javascript, console.log

I am trying to understand what is happening when I call console.log within another console.log(), like so:

```
console.log(console.log("Hello"));
```

My results are:

```
Hello
undefined
```

What is the outer console.log() trying to show that is undefined?

Comment: The return value of `console.log()` is `undefined`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Console returns undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360904/console-returns-undefined)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically

```
typeof console = "object"
typeof console.log = "function"
typeof console.log("Hello") = "undefined"
```

So the first console.log(x); has an undefined where there is an x.

Answer (score 2):

The first call of `console.log("Hello")` prints "Hello" and returns `undefined` value to the next call. Thus the order is

```
Hello // from console.log("Hello");
undefined // from console.log(undefined);
```

Answer (score 1):

The return value of console.log("Hello") : "void" is about the same as "undefined" in javascript

Answer (score 1):

`console.log()` returns nothing, it just prints to the console. Thus, you are trying to `log` an undefined value.

As you can see below, we mimic the behavior of `console.log` with a `document.write`. The second value is undefined, as expected:

```js
document.write(document.write("Hello"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are writing this code in `console` and `console.log()` is not return any value.
if you  write same code in any function then you get different result

for E.g

```
function test()
{
console.log("test")
return 1;
}
```

Now when you execute `test()` function in console you will get

```
test
1
```

and if you define another function with not return type..

```
  function test2()
    {
    console.log("test")
    }
```

Then you get

```
test
undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

If a JavaScript method does not have a explicit return then it returns `undefined` object. console.log according to chrome looks like:

```
console.log(object [, object, ...])
```

So, the inner console.log('Hello') //Print output browser console but it returns `undefined` so outer console.log is printing `undefined`.