# Warning: PhantomJS not found

Tags: node.js, debian, phantomjs

I have installed nodejs 0.10.15 on debian 6. Using npm I have then installed:

```
sudo npm install grunt-cli -g
```

I have also executed npm install in my local test directory (downloading the necessary dependencies to the node_modules directory) which contains the following package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "sample-name",
  "version": "1.4.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-qunit": ">0.0.0",
    "grunt-qunit-istanbul": ">0.0.0"
  }
}
```

here is the output when installing phantomjs:

```
...
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/myuser/Test/node_modules/grunt-contrib-qunit/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /home/myuser/Test/node_modules/grunt-qunit-istanbul/node_modules/grunt-lib-phantomjs-istanbul/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
grunt@0.4.1 node_modules/grunt
├── which@1.0.5
...
```

But when I run **grunt test** from the test dir I get:

```
Running PhantomJS...ERROR
>> In order for this task to work properly, PhantomJS must be installed locally
>> via NPM. If you're seeing this message, generally that means the NPM install
>> has failed. Please submit an issue providing as much detail as possible at:
>> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-phantomjs/issues
Warning: PhantomJS not found. Use --force to continue.
```

If I run the phantomjs script installed in the previous specified location nothing happens, I get exit code 127 though (indicating problem PATH :http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html). If I cat the phantomjs bash script it looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var path = require('path')
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn

var binPath = require(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'lib', 'phantomjs')).path

var args = process.argv.slice(2)

// For Node 0.6 compatibility, pipe the streams manually, instead of using
// `{ stdio: 'inherit' }`.
var cp = spawn(binPath, args)
cp.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
cp.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)
cp.on('exit', process.exit)

process.on('SIGTERM', function() {
  cp.kill('SIGTERM')
  process.exit(1)
})
```

As I understand this means that phantomjs is executed inside node. If I start node enter the path var I get:

```
:~$ env node
> var path = require('path')
undefined
>
```

(which I understand is default behavior: [node.js displays "undefined" on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457389/node-js-displays-undefined-on-the-console))

Any suggestions to further debug this problem?

Comment: What is your projects folder hierarchy and where is phantomjs in this hierarchy?

Comment: Tests are located here: /home/myuser/Test/ and phantomjs is located in the above destination (output from running npm install)

Answer (score 36):

Try running

`npm uninstall phantomjs`

then running

`npm install phantomjs -g`

This should make sure phantom's installed with the command line, so that grunt can use it, and also should make sure that it installed cleanly.

Comment: Where should that be executed from? I get: module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/home/myuser/Test/install'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
when running from terminal

Comment: @jserup It should be executed from the same directory that grunt is, which should coincide with the top level directory of your project. There should be a `node_modules` folder in whereever that is, as well as your `package.json`.

Comment: You don't mean "npm uninstall phantomjs" and "npm install phantomjs -g" instead of "node"? Using npm I can uninstall and reinstall it in the root of the directory but I still get the same error when I run "grunt test" : Warning: PhantomJS not found. Use --force to continue.

Comment: @jserup Thanks for the heads up! Apparently I needed more coffee.

Comment: Hm after upgrading from debian 6 to 7 the problem disappeared.

Comment: Doesn't work. Get the same error when executing that command.

Comment: This helped me with macOS.

Answer (score 11):

Try running the following in your terminal:

```
npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.14 --ignore-scripts
```

Answer (score 2):

Try 
`npm install grunt-mocha -D`

See more details at https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-phantomjs/issues/22

Comment: Doesn't work. Get the same error when executing that command.