# Buster.js using a HTTP Proxy returns "undefined"

Tags: javascript, proxy, buster.js

I'm trying to test my webapp with [Buster.js](http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/) but I can't get the HTTP proxy working.

When I try to run the test I only get a `undefined` message

```
$ buster-test --verbose
Running tests: Browser tests
undefined
undefined
```

I tried to find a solution to this problem online but It's kinda hard to search for an "undefined" message. It looks a bit like this problem [node.js displays "undefined" on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457389/node-js-displays-undefined-on-the-console)...

Anyone got any clue what might be the problem?

My config looks like this:

```
var config = exports;

config["Browser tests"] = {
    environment: "browser",
    sources: ["jquery.js"],
    tests: ["proxy-test.js"],
    resources: {
        "/en": "http://docs.busterjs.org:80/en/"
    }
};
```

And my test looks like this:

```
var strftime = window.strftime;

var assert = buster.assert;

buster.testCase("Ajax Testcase", {

    setUp: function () {
        this.timeout = 5000;
    },

    "Should get http://docs.busterjs.org/en/latest/": function (done) {

        $.ajaxSetup({timeout:1000});

        $.ajax("en/latest/").done(function(evt) {

            done();

        }).fail(function(evt) {

            assert(false); // test still times out..

        });

    }
});
```

I forked the tests and added my own here: https://github.com/tiemevanveen/demos/tree/master/buster-proxy-tests

I also created an issue on the buster github: https://github.com/busterjs/buster/issues/382

Comment: Are you running the latest version of buster, 0.7.x?

Comment: Yes Buster.JS version 0.7.6 Beta 5

Comment: I'll investigate :) In the meantime, you can try using buster.env.contextPath + "/en/latest/" so you're 100% sure you're using the correct URL. You still shouldn't just get "undefined" printed to the terminal, though.

Comment: See https://github.com/tiemevanveen/demos