# What does the `undefined` mean in node.js console?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote some code in the **Node.js** console, and noticed sometimes it return an `undefined`.
  See the following code.

Some lines return `undefined` but some don't.
What does the `undefined` mean?

```
PS D:\test\hello> node
> "two\nlines"
'two\nlines'
> var s = "hello, world"     
undefined
> s.charAt(0)
'h'
> s.charAt(s.length -1)
'd'
> var anyString = 'Mozilla';
undefined
> console.log(anyString.substring(3, 0));
Moz
undefined
```

Comment: `undefined`, in this context, means the statement doesn't have anything to return. More details at [node-js-displays-undefined-on-the-console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457389/node-js-displays-undefined-on-the-console)

Comment: But what does the last line , it returns `undefined` but also returns `Moz`?

Comment: There are two statements there. the inner one returns Moz whereas the outer doesn't return anything. Hence `undefined`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But what does the last line , it returns undefined but also returns Moz?
>
> ```
> > console.log(anyString.substring(3, 0));
> Moz
> undefined
> ```

`console.log` explicitly outputs to the console, which is the `Moz` you're seeing. It then returns a value (or well, it doesn't), which is the value `undefined`, which is logged to the console because you're in the interactive environment and that's what it does.

The point of using the interactive command line is to be able to try operations and see their result instantly, without complex `alert` or debugging setups. You type a command, you see its result. Sometimes that result is the value `undefined`, sometimes it's another value.