# Console.log is undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm currently in the process of learning Node via "Learnyounode". 
However, when testing some javascript files on my computer, anytime I try to run even a simple "Hello World"

```
console.log("Hello World");
```

It gives me an error returning

```
Error: 'console' is undefined.
```

Is this a problem with my Command prompt or an error on my system? do I need to re-install sometime for Javascript? my code works fine in my Browser console, but not in my local Command lines.

Any help would appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the following post, which may explain the result you are seeing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457389/node-js-displays-undefined-on-the-console

Comment: Here's your problem: http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2016/06/node-js-error-console-is-undefined/

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as accepted if it solved your problem :) [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know starting with NodeJS can be difficult... Try the follwing:

```
1. Create a .js file... call it test.js
2. In the file write command:

    console.log('hello world from node');

3. save the file.
4. Navigate to that directory and type:

    node test.js

Now you will see the output.
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you! It was because I wasn't leading it with node. The output worked, and now I'm off to learning!