# Node - how to stop undefined when module.exports.repl doesn't exist?

Tags: node.js, node-repl

As indicated in [node.js displays "undefined" on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8457389/631619) node will say undefined intentionally and is not usually an issue.

The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18487887/631619 indicates that you can set

```
module.exports.repl.ignoreUndefined = true;
```

However when in node I find `module.exports` (with tab completion) but there is no "repl" namespace within it.

How to address this and turn off the undefined message ?

```
node is 4.2.6
```

Comment: Are you saying that `repl` is not found in the autocompleter (which is occasionally true of dynamically registered properties) or are you saying that when you attempt to access `repl` it, itself, is `undefined`, because even if `repl` was undefined, you ought to be able to replace it with an object, with the property you are looking for. Not entirely certain that will be sufficient, but you aren't going to do any harm to your node install by setting it.