# for loop returns 0 if array length more than 1

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am doing a coding challenge where you are given an array of string like so: `[life, Petes kata, eating, kata]` and your code is supposed to return a value based of of what's in the string:

```
kata = 5
function paul(x) {
    let returnString = 0
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x.includes('life') === true) {
            returnString += 5
        } else if (x.includes('eating') === true) {
            returnString += 1
        } else if (x.includes('Petes kata') === true) {
            returnString += 10
        }
    }

    return returnString
}
```

At the moment my function works fine if there is only one word in the array. `life` returns 5, and `Petes kata` returns 10, as it should.
However when there is more than 1 word in the array, the function will always return 0, and I am not sure why.

I thought that wrapping the if statements with a for loop would make the function add to returnString several times, and if it were only working on the first word I could also understand that, but returning 0 has been puzzling me for a while.

Comment: So you are aware, in markdown you only need a single backtick on either side of an inline bit of code, such as a variable name; three backticks are to be used when defining a block of code.

Comment: The `=== true` in your conditions isn’t necessary and can be removed. It sounds like you don’t need the loop at all: `x.includes('life')` will be `true` or `false` regardless of what `i` is.

Comment: I want the if statements to apply to every item in the array, that's why I put the loop in. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `else if`? `paul(["life", "eating"])` returns `10` because for every item of the array, you test if `"life"` is included in the array. It always is, so you add `5` and `x.includes('eating')` is never checked because you use `else if` instead of another `if`. See the documentation of [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). What is `paul(["life", "life"])` supposed to return? `5` or `10`? If `5`, then use just `.includes` without a loop. If `10`, _compare_ inside the loop: `x[i] === "life"`.

Comment: `[life life]` should return 10, not 5. Sorry I wasn't clear on this, it should be a cumulative score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the change to requirement, you can approach the problem of counting occurrences like so....

```js
 function paul(x) {            
        let score = 0;   
        x.forEach(s =>  {
          if(s == 'life') score+=5;
          else if(s == 'eating') score +=1;
          else if(s == 'Petes kata') score +=10;
        })            
        return score
    }
    console.log(paul(['life', 'Petes kata', 'eating', 'kata','life']))
```

Comment: I guess the question is, if 'life' is in the array twice, would you return 5 or 10 (5 for each time it appears). If 10, you do need that loop right?

Comment: It should be 10, if `life` is in the array twice, sorry I i wasn't clear

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this is returning undefined when presented with a long array? I am testing an array with a length of 30+ and it is returning `0 undefined`

Comment: nope, I'd need to see the array, I doubt it has anything to do with the length of the array

Comment: The arrays look like this: `eating,kata,eating,kata,eating,eating,eating,life,Petes kata,kata,life,kata,kata,life,eating,kata,eating` 
You can also test it out yourself here https://www.codewars.com/kata/57ee31c5e77282c24d000024/train/javascript

Comment: @imstupidpleasehelp The function is not returning `undefined`. That’s just the return value of `console.log` that you see in a REPL. See [node.js displays “undefined” on the console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8457389/4642212). It’s returning `0`, because this isn’t the expected input. An array of strings looks like `["kata", "eating", "etc."]`, not like `kata,eating,etc.`.

Comment: Then I suppose that's the fault of the challenge and not Keith's code, Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misunderstood the use of Array's `.includes()` method. At the moment you're using a for-loop to iterate over each element in the array manually and try to execute `.includes()` on `x` - a reference to the input array. Actually that's not neccessary as the `.includes()` method **automatically** goes over each element in your array.

Something like this is sufficient:

```js
let arr = ["life", "Petes kata", "eating", "kata"];

function paul(x) {
  let returnString = 0;

  if (x.includes('life')) {
    returnString += 5;
  }
  if (x.includes('eating')) {
    returnString += 1;
  }
  if (x.includes('Petes kata')) {
    returnString += 10;
  }

  return returnString;
}

console.log(paul(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you use `for` statement on your code. Maybe you wrote wrong code.
Please try like this.

```
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
   if (x[i].includes('life')) {
     returnString += 5
   } else if (x[i].includes('eating')) {
     returnString += 1
   } else if (x[i].includes('Petes kata')) {
     returnString += 10
   }
}
```